# find a minimum value in an array of floats

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minimum

How would one go about finding the minimum value in an array of 100 floats in python?
I have tried `minindex=darr.argmin()` and `print darr[minindex]` with `import numpy` (darr is the name of the array)

but I get:
`minindex=darr.argmin()`

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'argmin'`

what might be the problem? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: both answerers thank you, but not using numpy at all seemed better.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Python has a [`min()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min):

```
>>> darr = [1, 3.14159, 1e100, -2.71828]
>>> min(darr)
-2.71828
```

Comment: If your (numpy) array is more than one dimensional then you must use `darr.min()`, rather than `min(darr)`.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to use numpy, you must define `darr` to be a numpy array, not a `list`:

```
import numpy as np
darr = np.array([1, 3.14159, 1e100, -2.71828])
print(darr.min())
```

`darr.argmin()` will give you the index corresponding to the minimum.

The reason you were getting an error is because `argmin` is a method understood by numpy arrays, but not by Python `lists`.

Comment: True, though under the hood `np.amin(darr)` ends up calling `np.asarray(darr).min()`, and is about 50% slower due to extra `__array_wrap__` code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the 2d array in order to get the min value of each row, then you have to push any gotten min value to another array and finally you need to get the min value of the array where each min row value was pushed

```
def get_min_value(self, table):
    min_values = []
    for i in range(0, len(table)):
        min_value = min(table[i])
        min_values.append(min_value)

    return min(min_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

If min value in array, you can try like:

```
>>> mydict = {"a": -1.5, "b": -1000.44, "c": -3}
>>> min(mydict.values())
-1000.44
```