# How to sort by value in descending order an Ordered Dictionary in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using an Ordered Dictionary which contains all the values (n_estimators and error rates from an OOB estimation, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674758/how-to-get-the-n-estimator-and-max-features-of-the-minimum-oob-error-and-use-the).

I want to get the values with the lowest error rates first in the dictionary.

For example, below you can see that 222 has the highest error rate.

```
OrderedDict([('RandomForest_AWA_Fp1, max_features=7', 
    [(220, 0.10833333333333328), 
     (221, 0.10833333333333328), 
     (222, 0.10952380952380958), 
     (223, 0.10833333333333328)])
])
```

I want to sort this dictionary in this order: 220, 221, 223, 222 (by value in descending order)

I have tried:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(error_rate.items(), key=lambda t: min(t[0])))
```

But I do not see any difference.

ERROR I GET:

```
 File "<ipython-input-85-0592e683c6a9>", line 3
    pp(dict(OrderedDict(sorted([(k, sorted(v, key=min)) for k, v in d.items()], key=lambda(k, v): min(v)))))
                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the input and expected output looks like by giving a clear and simple example (e.g. 3 items)?

Comment: Are you trying to sort by the value? if so check this: [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is formed of one item, so I am not sure whether you wanted to sort that too.  However, that appears to be the case form your linked question.

Since you mentioned `222` has the highest error value, I take it you wanted to also sort the values in the list.

```
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> d = OrderedDict([('RandomForest_AWA_Fp1, max_features=7', [(220, 0.10833333333333328), (221, 0.10833333333333328), (222, 0.10952380952380958), (223, 0.10833333333333328)])])
>>> pp(OrderedDict(sorted([(k, sorted(v, key=min)) for k, v in d.items()], key=lambda(k, v): min(v))))
OrderedDict([('RandomForest_AWA_Fp1, max_features=7', [(220, 0.10833333333333328), (221, 0.10833333333333328), (223, 0.10833333333333328), (222, 0.10952380952380958)])]{'RandomForest_AWA_Fp1, max_features=7': [(220, 0.10833333333333328),
                                                  (221, 0.10833333333333328),
                                                  (223, 0.10833333333333328),
                                                  (222, 0.10952380952380958)]}
```

Comment: I get an error  File "<ipython-input-85-0592e683c6a9>", line 3
    pp(dict(OrderedDict(sorted([(k, sorted(v, key=min)) for k, v in d.items()], key=lambda(k, v): min(v)))))
                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Aizzaac that works fine here!  Could you check if you missed a braces between copy/paste?